# Uses permission is not working in built apk

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

When  built my application, the built apk is not working any other devices. It is only working in my mobile. The error message i founded is user permission is not available and security exception. It is only working in my phone.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.dineshkumar.panicbutton">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/welcome"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Welcome"
        android:label="Panic Button"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Emergency" />
    <activity android:name=".Contacts" />
    <activity android:name=".ManualCadd" />
    <activity android:name=".Message" />
    <activity android:name=".Guide" />
    <activity android:name=".Updatecontacts" />
    <activity android:name=".ShowContacts" />

</application>
```

Comment: Please add some code for reference

Comment: you need to implement runtime permission for above 23 api targeting device

Answer (score 0):

Your device should have Android 6.0 version or above to handle Runtime Permissions. Also you need to set the Target SDK version to 23 or above for listing dangerous permissions.